# Running a Greengrass Core on a Raspberry Pi 3b+

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, raspberry-pi, aws-iot-greengrass

I have 2 greengrass cores, one is running on an AWS EC2 instance and the other is running on a Raspberry Pi.

In my project, I am sending video frames from my local machine to my RaspberryPi, then I process those frames, locate a marker with a QR code that is in the frame and send the coordinates of the marker to Greengrass. I am then reading those coordinates from my laptop.

In first scenario my greengrass was running on an EC2 instance (had it from before) and in order to boost performance I decided to run another greengrass core on my Raspberry Pi and use that one instead. My thinking was that instead of having a triangle Laptop->RBPi->EC2->Laptop I will essentially remove the EC2 instance and the cloud component from this process and therefore improve my performance.

The problem is that I do not see much/any difference in performance.

In both cases, if I want to connect to my greengrass core instance I use the AWS endpoint as the my "contact" point and the only difference is that in core's connectivity setting I am using my Raspberry Pi's IP address in one scenario and the IP address of the EC2 instance in the other. Am I wrong in doing it like this, is there another way?

How does this communication work in practice? Does my message go to the AWS endpoint somewhere in the cloud and is then sent to my greengrass core device (Raspberry Pi or EC2)?

Answer (score 0):

Greengrass is an IoT service, and due to its purpose, it uses fast and lightweight MQTT protocol for communication.
Its communication model is based on "Publish-Subscribe" model, with MQTT broker in the middle.

You are right saying the message goes to AWS endpoint - that would be the AWS IoT Core MQTT broker.
When a IoT device (i.e. RPI or EC2) runs Greengrass or in fact any other IoT MQTT client software, when it 'sends' a message - it publishes it to that broker on specific topic. On the other side there is another IoT device which in turn is subscribed to that topic through the same broker.

The broker acts like a hub where devices publish messages and subscribe to receive those messages with the use of topics, thus the communication is possible.

IoT devices need that broker to communicate, hence it really doesn't matter whether you run Greengrass on EC2 or RPI since both have to publish to subscribe to the topic on the AWS IoT broker.